# Use Logstash "%{[source]}" to show the file name only for the Elasticsearch Index

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I would like to use the filename from the source file as the index for my elasticsearch entries as we will have multiple different log files logging to Elasticsearch using FileBeats and LogStash.

Currently I have:

```
input
{
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
    json {
    source => "message"
    }   
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[source]}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
        user => ***
        password => ***
    }
}
```

This provides me with "C:\logs\test-20170518.json". I would like to have **test-20170518** used as the index only. Can this be done using the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used a grok filter plugin for that. Try this

```
input
{
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }  
    grok {
        match => [
            "source",
            "C:\\logs\\%{DATA:myIndex}.json"
      ]
    } 
}


output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        manage_template => false
        index => "%{[myIndex]}"
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
        user => ***
        password => ***
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! So essentially %{DATA:myIndex} creates a variable for the file name (myIndex) which can be called with "%{[myIndex]}".

Comment: Can you explain what is "source"? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: It is the source from which the data are parsed. In this case there are JSON data in the field `message` which will be parsed in a JSON. [Check this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-source)